# Put an application window as wallpaper

Tags: silverlight, windows-7, .net-4.0, wallpaper

I'm looking to put an application window behind all other windows.
I was thinking of using .NET 4 and WPF or Silverlight.

I don't have any specific drawing code, I just want my application window as my desktop wallpaper while retaining the interactivity (no mucking around with screenshots etc).

Is this even possible and if so, how?

**Edit:** I'm using Windows 7 x64.

**Edit 2:** I know the desktop is drawn to a window with id 0 (or something like that). Can't I use interop calls to put my window as a child of window 0?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows XP and previous versions, [use Active Desktop](http://hubpages.com/hub/active-desktop) ad set a web page that runs a Silverlight application.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I'm running Windows 7 x64.